# SQL MAX() function selects the greatest in absolute value even if I don't use ABS()?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, aggregate

I am trying to get the max of a column, and it is returning the maximum number in absolute value. For example, say we have TABLE:

```
 TAG | VALUE
-------------
  A  |  1.5
  B  | -3.0
  C  |  0.5
  D  |  2.0
  E  | -2.5
```

And the query I am doing is simple as

```
SELECT TAG, MAX(VALUE)
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY TAG
```

But the result that I get is

```
-3.0
```

Which is technically the highest value in absolute, but not the highest overall (2.0). This VALUE field is stored as nvarchar(255) and I do not have edit permissions for the table itself. Maybe I can alter it's format in a new query (assuming that would solve the issue)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT TAG, MAX(cast(VALUE as decimal(10,1)))
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY TAG
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked! Appreciate the lightning fast response.